# Is the electric potential positive or zero in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-fields, potential

I have recently been learning about Electric Potential, and I came across this problem:

"If we have a charge of -q and a charge of +q, find the Electric Potential at a point P such that P is the midpoint of the line segment connecting the Negative and Positive Charges".

[image]

Intuitively, I thought that the answer would just be 0, because just looking at the picture it seems like the sum of the Electric Potential will be 0 because the -q charge will "cancel out" the +q charge. However, I'm a little unsure of this, because I've also learned that Electric Potential is "a scalar quantity". In this case, the Electric Potential would be positive?

Could someone confirm if Electric Potential is vector or scalar quantity, and also confirm the correct answer to this problem for me?

Answer (score 1):

the potential would be zero half way due to the fact that zero work would be needed to get to that point as a line perpendicular to the line connecting them at the half way mark would.experience no  force  in the direction of motion on this path

Answer (score -1):

Potential is by definition a kind of **Work**(Work done by a unit charge) which is a scalar quantity. Yes the potential is zero at the center provided both the charges are exactly identical except for the opposite sign of charge. But this is not because its a vector. Why is zero then?

I leave it to you to show this explicit using the definition of [Electric Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential).